# Plotting directed graphs in Python in a way that show all edges separately

Tags: python, networkx, graph-visualization

I'm using Python to simulate a process that takes place on directed graphs.  I would like to produce an animation of this process.

The problem that I've run into is that most Python graph visualization libraries combine pairs of directed edges into a single edge.  For example, [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov) draws only two edges when displaying the following graph, whereas I would like to display each of the four edges separately:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()

G.add_edges_from([
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 2),
    (2, 1),
])

plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
nx.draw(G)
```

[image: Output from NetworkX; parallel edges are overlapping, so only two lines are displayed]

I would like to display something like this, with each parallel edge drawn separately:

[image: Desired output format; parallel edges are drawn separately]

The question [R reciprocal edges in igraph in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711540/r-reciprocal-edges-in-igraph-in-r) seems to deal with the same issue, but the solution there is for the R igraph library, not the Python one.

Is there an easy way to produce this style of plot using an existing Python graph visualization library?  It would be a bonus if it could support multigraphs.

I'm open to solutions that invoke an external program to produce the images.  I'd like to generate a whole series of animation frames, so the solution must be automated.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053686/networkx-overlapping-edges-when-visualizing-multigraph

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) tools appear to display distinct edges.

For example, giving this:

```
digraph G {
  A -> B;
  A -> B;
  A -> B;
  B -> C;

  B -> A;
  C -> B;
}
```

to `dot` produces:

[image: example graph]

Graphviz's input language is pretty simple so you can generate it on your own, though searching for "python graphviz" does turn up a couple of libraries including a [`graphviz` module on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/).

Here's python that generates the above graph using the `graphviz` module:

```
from graphviz import Digraph

dot = Digraph()
dot.node('A', 'A')
dot.node('B', 'B')
dot.node('C', 'C')
dot.edges(['AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'BC', 'BA', 'CB'])

print(dot.source)
dot.render(view=True)
```

Comment: It turns out that NetworkX can [export .dot files using pydot](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.nx_pydot) or [pygraphviz](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.nx_agraph), so this works perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: Both links are dead @JoshRosen

Comment: I am having following error: `Format: "pdf" not recognized. Use one of`@Laurence Gonsalves

Comment: @alper I believe it's possible to select the output formats at build time. You may need to install a different distribution of graphviz, or build your own.

Answer (score 17):

Maybe I am a little late but I found another solution to you issue. I am posting it so that it can be helpful if somebody has the same problem.

It is possible to plot directed graphs with `networkx` using `matplotlib` in a way that the edges appear separately, by passing the argument [`connectionstyle`](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html) to the function [`networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw`](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx


# create a directed multi-graph
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 2),
    (2, 1),
])
# plot the graph
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
nx.draw(G, connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.1')
plt.show()  # pause before exiting
```

Here you see the result:

[image: The result]

See also the [documentation of `matplotlib.patches.ConnectionStyle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ConnectionStyle.html) about the argument `connectionstyle`.

Comment: This seems to make arcs even for vertices connected with a single directed edge. Is there any easy workaround for that?

Answer (score 13):

Using NetworkX, a possible workaround which avoids file I/O and uses dot via pydot for layout is:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from io import BytesIO

g = nx.dodecahedral_graph()
d = nx.drawing.nx_pydot.to_pydot(g)
    # `d` is a `pydot` graph object,
    # `dot` options can be easily set
    # attributes get converted from `networkx`,
    # use set methods to control
    # `dot` attributes after creation
png_str = d.create_png()
sio = BytesIO() # file-like string, appropriate for imread below
sio.write(png_str)
sio.seek(0)
img = mpimg.imread(sio)
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()  # added to make the script wait before exiting
```

for why `seek(0)` is needed, see [How to create an image from a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664861/how-to-create-an-image-from-a-string-in-python)

If within the IPython (qt)console, then the above will print inline and a more direct approach is:

```
import networkx as nx
from IPython.display import Image

g = nx.dodecahedral_graph()
d = nx.drawing.nx_pydot.to_pydot(g)

png_str = d.create_png()
Image(data=png_str)
```

Comment: This example needs to be updated: `nx.to_pydot`  is no longer available. Instead you should `pip install pydotplus` and then use `nx.drawing.nx_pydot.to_pydot` instead.

Comment: Thanks for raising the need to update this example, I updated it. `pydotplus` has already been reverted to `pydot` in upstream `networkx`, please see [this PR](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/2272).

Comment: If pydotplus does not find your `graphviz` instalation it will throw `InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found`. A workaround is to add it to system path for current execution like this: `import os` then `os.environ["PATH"] += r";C:\Anaconda\envs\testes\Library\bin\graphviz"` where you should replace the folder where your graphviz executables are located.

Comment: `pydotplus` is an unmaintained fork of `pydot`. `pydot == 1.2.3` will look for GraphViz executables only in the `$PATH`, for the reasons described in [this issue](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/issues/126#issuecomment-232469905) and issues referenced in it. Adding the relevant paths to the environment's `$PATH` variable isn't a workaround, but the proper way of declaring where GraphViz is located. Please consider using `.bashrc` or an equivalent, instead of modifying `os.environ` at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by using the matplotlib interface:

```
G=nx.MultiGraph ([(1, 2),
   (2, 3),
   (3, 2),
   (2, 1)])
pos = {1: (0.4,0.5), 2: (0.5,0.5), 3: (0.6,0.5)}
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color = 'k', node_size = 100, alpha = 1)
ax = plt.gca()
for e in G.edges:
    ax.annotate("",
                xy=pos[e[0]], xycoords='data',
                xytext=pos[e[1]], textcoords='data',
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color="0.5",
                                shrinkA=5, shrinkB=5,
                                patchA=None, patchB=None,
                                connectionstyle="arc3,rad=rrr".replace('rrr',str(2*(e[2]-0.5))
                                ),
                                ),
                )
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]