# Networkx Directed Graph Python

Tags: python, graph, label, draw, networkx

I want to draw a directed graph with Python library Networkx, the problem is that when I have a connection from Node1 to Node1, and back from Node2 to Node2, their labels are overwritten.

Is there a method to draw curves from one node to another, or a way to configure labels position?

[image]

In screenshot you can see that I have two directed lines but only one label, second label is over first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379448/plotting-directed-graphs-in-python-in-a-way-that-show-all-edges-separately

Comment: I resolved with label_pos=0.2

Answer (score 1):

It was resolved with label_pos=0.2