# Create multiple directed edges in a networkx graph

Tags: python, dataframe, networkx

I want to display the information in the following example dataset as a directed graph with multiple edges between nodes.

Attached is an example of the kind of graph I expect, as well as my code, which does not produce the expected output.

Thanks,

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'source', 'destination', edge_attr='number of passengers', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
pos = nx.random_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, 
        pos=pos)
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "Edge_label")
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

| date | source | destination | number of passengers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | NY | BERLIN | 10 |
| 2019-01-02 | NY | PARIS | 50 |
| 2019-01-03 | NY | BERLIN | 40 |
| 2019-01-04 | BERLIN | PARIS | 20 |
| 2019-01-05 | NY | PARIS | 15 |
| 2019-01-06 | BERLIN | NY | 17 |

Comment: Have a look at https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multidigraph.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943439/how-to-draw-multigraph-in-networkx-using-matplotlib-or-graphviz

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler this answer is not give solution to my problem , it's not deal with multiple direct graph that one node have two or more edges to  other node , and plot the label for each edge . maybe you find something I miss ...

Comment: The networkx link is for MultiDiGraph, which is "a directed graph class that can store multiedges. Multiedges are multiple edges between two nodes." As far as I can see, that's exactly what you're looking for: "a directed graph with multiple edges between nodes." The StackOverflow link I provided is an old but still helpful guide to actually display multiple edges in matplotlib.