# draw a graph with two edge between two nodes with networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

how can I draw a graph with no direction with two edge between two nodes with networkx in python language

I got help from chatGPT it gives me this code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_node("A")
G.add_node("B")

G.add_edge("A", "B", weight=3)
G.add_edge("A", "B", weight=5)
print(G.edges)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight="bold")
plt.show()
```

but when I run this still have one edge between two nodes A and B like this picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkeYh.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

NetworkX `Graph` objects do not support having multiple edges between the same two nodes, and hence the output of `print(G.edges)` is just `[('A', 'B')]`, i.e. a single edge. To support multiple edges between the same two nodes, you need to use a `MultiGraph` object, and assign edge ids to your edges.

```py
import networkx as nx

edge_to_weight = {
    ("A", "B", 0) : 3,
    ("A", "B", 1) : 5,
}

G = nx.MultiGraph()
for edge, weight in edge_to_weight.items():
    G.add_edge(*edge, weight=weight)
```

The next issue is that Networkx does not support plotting of `MultiGraph` edges, so you have to rely on third party software to do so. The options there are either [Graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14945560/2912349), or my [Netgraph](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph). Graphviz is battle-hardened but doesn't create matplotlib plots, so your ability to style the plots is limited (and requires you to learn the dot mini-language). Netgraph does produce matplotlib plots but the support for `MultiGraph` objects is new (requiring you to install from the dev branch) so there might be some hick-ups.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from netgraph import MultiGraph # pip install https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph/archive/dev.zip

MultiGraph(G, node_labels=True, edge_labels=edge_to_weight, edge_color='tab:blue')

plt.show()
```

[image]