# Simultaneously add multiple parallel edges - Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I'm sure this is very basic, but is it possible to specify an arbitrary number of edges between nodes when constructing a graph? I've been searching under terms: 'directed graph', 'multiple directed graph', 'parallel edges', 'add_edges', etc.

Say, I have four nodes: A, B, C, D and I want to show:
A to B, has 600 edges
A to C, has 100 edges
A to D, has 400 edges

I'm thinking something like:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_node('a', {'b': 600, 'c':100, 'd':400})
G.add_node('b')
G.add_node('c')
G.add_node('d')
```

(Except, obviously this isn't correct.)

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/tutorial/tutorial.html
you have to add edges from a list of tuples:

```
import networkx as nx

a = {'b': 600, 'c':100, 'd':400}
MG=nx.MultiGraph()
MG.add_weighted_edges_from([('a', k, v) for k, v in a.iteritems()], weight='weight')
print MG.edges(data='weight')
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'c', 100), ('a', 'b', 600), ('a', 'd', 400)]
```

Comment: You've added single edges and assigned a weight to them (possibly what the OP needs, but not what  he asked for).  To add multiple edges, you can do something like `MG.add_edges_from([('a','b')]*600)`

Comment: Thanks! Both methods give me multiple edges which is great. When I plot them, though, I only see a single edge line from node 'a' to the targets. I expected (hoped?) to see multiple separate edges lines. I'm trying to plot the amount of interactions from a source to its targets (something like those flight-path plots).

Comment: By default you can not plot multi-edged graph by networkx. Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379448/plotting-directed-graphs-in-python-in-a-way-that-show-all-edges-separately

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to plot "Multi-edges graph" with NetworkX or is there any work around solution to do this ?