# Plotting multi-edge directed graphs using pyvis in a way that shows all edges separately

Tags: python, networkx, graph-visualization, pyvis

Note: This post is directly related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379448/plotting-directed-graphs-in-python-in-a-way-that-show-all-edges-separately), except that I am looking for a solution in `pyvis`.

I would like to plot a directed graph with multiedges, that is, each pair of nodes is connected with two edges in opposite directions. In order to that, it is important, that the two edges do not overlap visually. When using `networkx.draw()` this problem can be solved by passing `connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.1'` to `nx.draw()` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59917248/8792159). However, I am using for a solution in `pyvis`.

Example using `networkx.draw()`:

```py
import networkx
from pyvis.network import Network

# create a graph
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 2),
    (2, 1),
])


# draw with networkx using the proposed solution
nx.draw(G, connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.1')
```

[image]

```
# This is how the graph currently looks with pyvis
nt = Network('500px', '500px',directed=True)
nt.from_nx(G)
nt.show('nx.html')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version are you using? I just tried running your code:

```py
import networkx as nx
from pyvis.network import Network

# create a graph
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 2),
    (2, 1),
])

# This is how the graph currently looks with pyvis
nt = Network('500px', '500px',directed=True)
nt.from_nx(G)
nt.show('nx.html')
```

and I obtain the result you are looking for:

[image: two nodes with arc edges]

You can find the output HTML here: https://pastecode.io/s/anav9333

I am using version `pyvis=0.3.0`

Comment: Ha! You're right! Unfortunately, I have a new machine now and can't remember which version I used on the old one. Besides, the old machine was running Windows (don't know if this might have an effect on the layout?)

Comment: It is probably due to an older version. I don't think the operating system has any impact on the result, given that it is Javascript running on the browser's engine. If my answer helped you, feel free to mark it as accepted answer :)