# Converting jpeg string to PIL image object

Tags: python, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I've been handed a list of files from the backend of an application that are supposed to be jpeg files. However for the life of me I haven't been able to convert them into PIL image objects. When I call

```
str(curimg)
```

I get back:

```
<type 'str'>
```

. I have tried using open(), .read, io.BytesIO(img.read() and also doing nothing to it, but it keeps seeing it as a string. When i print the string, I get unrecognizable characters. Does anyone know how to tell python how to intepret this string as a jpeg and convert it into a pill image where I can call .size and np.array on?

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664861/how-to-create-an-image-from-a-string-in-python) have the answer you seek?

Comment: Did you try [`Image.fromstring()`](http://effbot.org/zone/pythondoc-compact.htm#Image.fromstring-function) ?

Comment: ^^ The only thing is I dont know how to get the size that fromstring() needs? All i'm given is a string.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to pass a StringIO object to PIL and open it that way.

ie:

```
from PIL import Image
import StringIO
tempBuff = StringIO.StringIO()
tempBuff.write(curimg)
tempBuff.seek(0) #need to jump back to the beginning before handing it off to PIL
Image.open(tempBuff)
```

Comment: I'm using python 3.6 and I am getting this error `"StringIO cannot be used to open an image. "
ValueError: StringIO cannot be used to open an image. Binary data must be used instead.` if I use this method

Answer (score 26):

```
from PIL import Image
import io
Image.open(io.BytesIO(image))
```

Note:

If image is on the web; you need to download it first.

```
import requests
image = requests.get(image_url).content  #download image from web
```

And then pass it to io module.

```
io.BytesIO(image)
```

If image is in your hd; you can open directly with PIL.

```
Image.open('image_file.jpg')  #image in your HD
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, none of the solutions above worked.

I finally managed to read the string properly like this:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.frombytes('RGB', (640, 480), img_str, 'raw')
```

To test it, you can do something like

```
image = Image.open("some.png")
print(image.mode, image.size) # OUT: 'RGB' (640, 480)
image = Image.frombytes('RGB', (640, 480), image.tobytes(), 'raw')
image.show()
```

Comment: I just came across this. I am having a similar issue. If you still have a fresh knowledge of this, can you explain some things to me please?

Comment: I don't use PIL anymore, but I can try to help

Comment: Hello @Vandavv, thanks for your willingness to help. I've been able to resolve it. The pictures now display. But I'm having another issue.

I wanna update the retrieved image which is displayed in jpg format. How do I go about it plz?

The image label (i.e the qpixmap label) is self.passlb

So in my sql update statement, I tried:
            
 ```sql = (my update statement here)
              values(self.fullname.text(),
              self.passlb.pixmap()
...)```

It didn't work.
Any clue about the method I should use in updating a qpixmap label?

Comment: @VanDavv, thank you so much!  I have a PpmImageFile object but couldn't figure out how to convert it.  Got some clue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65597315/how-to-return-a-list-of-pil-image-files-from-fastapi-response) but couldn't figure out everything.

Answer (score 0):

@CEO (per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883432/converting-jpeg-string-to-pil-image-object/50798272?noredirect=1#comment122361614_50798272) comment) I don't know how what role SQL plays here, and I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, but I recall I had some issues and this is what works for my case, hope it helps

```
frame = self._rawNode.display_frame.copy()
width = int(self.customLayout.geometry().width())
height = int(frame.shape[0] * (width / frame.shape[1]))
display_frame = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.resize(frame, (width, height)), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
qImg = QtGui.QImage(display_frame.data, width, height, 3 * width, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(qImg)
self.Imagelabel.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
```

Comment: hello @vanDavv, I've resolved it. It's fine now. I'm presently having a different issue I'm trying to resolve but so unfortunate I've been denied from asking questions here.

Comment: No worries, happy to help whenever I can