# Adding an Image to the python GUI from within the script

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, base64

```
import base64
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

imgstring="/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4QCMRXhpZgAASUAADADEBFAH/2Q=="
imgdata = base64.b64decode(imgstring)

imgfinal = open('here.jpg','wb')
imgfinal.write(imgdata)


root=Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imgdata)) #This Doesn't work for me !
panel = Label(root,image=img)
panel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

What I am trying to do is to add an image to the gui from the python script itself.
The imgstring variable is a shortened version of the actual image code.
The "here.jpg" file is a test used to make sure the code actually converts the imgdata bytes into an image.

Edit: -How can I add the image from its string to the label ?
-What should I change the line " img = ImageTk.PhotoImage.. " to ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I add the image to the Label panel from its base64 code?

Comment: I have tried to write your `imgstring` to a file but the 'here.jpg' I obtain is not a valid image, maybe there is a typo in the string?

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883432/converting-jpeg-string-to-pil-image-object) can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tkinter `PhotoImage()` accepts a base64 string as input:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
imgstring = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4QCMRXhpZgAASUAADADEBFAH/2Q=="
img = PhotoImage(data=imgstring)
panel = Label(root,image=img)
panel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If the image is a .jpg as suggested by the name 'here.jpg' in the question, then it won't work since tkinter doesn't support this format but this solution would work for a .png image.

Comment: How are they any different ? I used an online jpg to png converter and then looked at their code with notepad after encoding both of them to base64. There is no difference. EDIT: The online converter was faulty, it didn't do anything aside from renaming the .jpg to .png

Comment: You don't need to save it to a file, just use the `img` in your label. I have updated my example.