# How to return a list of PIL image files from fastapi response?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, fastapi, uvicorn

I have created an rest-api using fastapi, which takes a document (pdf) as input and return a jpeg image of it, I am using a library called docx2pdf for conversion.

```
from docx2pdf import convert_to    
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/file/convert")
async def convert(doc: UploadFile = File(...)):
    if doc.filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        # convert pdf to image
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as path:
            doc_results = convert_from_bytes(
                doc.file.read(), output_folder=path, dpi=350, thread_count=4
            )

            print(doc_results)

        return doc_results if doc_results else None
```

This is the output of `doc_results`, basically a list of PIL image files

```
[<PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2975x3850 at 0x7F5AB4C9F9D0>, <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2975x3850 at 0x7F5AB4C9FB80>]
```

If I run my current code, it is returning the doc_results as json output and I am not being able to load those images in another API.

How can I return image files without saving them to local storage? So, I can make a request to this api and get the response and work on the image directly.

Also, if you know any improvements I can make in the above code to speed up is also helpful.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not return that unless you convert it to something universal.

> <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=RGB size=2975x3850 at 0x7F5AB4C9F9D0

This basically says, **You have an object of PIL at your memory here is the location for it**.

The best thing you can do is, convert them to bytes and return an array of bytes.

---

You can create a function that takes a PIL image and returns the byte value from it.

```py
import io

def get_bytes_value(image):
    img_byte_arr = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(img_byte_arr, format='JPEG')
    return img_byte_arr.getvalue()
```

Then you can use this function when returning the response.

```py
return [get_bytes_value(image) for image in doc_results] if doc_results else None
```

Comment: Can you provide some example code to help me out a bit, I have been trying to achieve it from last few hours but so far not able to figure our how to return an array of bytes ?

Comment: I am getting a error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`, I have tried this solution but didn't worked for me.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions for that error from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339876/error-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-in)?

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue, I had to base64 encoding.

Comment: Ah great, glad it helped.